# get text data from end user, with one field having uneditable list of drop down values(others input by end user)

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a requirement, where some 14-15 fields of data have to be asked from the end user and some processing has to be done for those values.

But one of the values should be pre-filled with a drop down list of values, and user can only select one of the values in that list. Also, the user can add a suffix value to this fixed value(by fixed value i mean value in drop down list selected by end user). So this parameter when sent to the server for processing, is fixed value+suffix.

I want to know if this type of form processing can be done using bean/jsp. Or with any other method.

If you could give me a code sample for implementing this (whether bean or other method) then that would be great.

The processing that has to be done after the user submits all 14-15 values is written as java code. I should be able to invoke this code to do processing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done using servlets/JSP.

You need to generate apage containing an HTML form. This form will have to contain a select element withh all the fixed options, and a text input where the user has to enter the suffix. When submitted, the servlet/JSP will have to get the submitted values from the request parameters, and do its processing.

A code sample would be too hard to give you. You need to read a whole tutorial about HTML forms, the servlet API and how JSPs work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.. Can you point me to a good book or tutorial on this subject?

Comment: What you know and don't know is not clear from your question? Do you know HTML? Do you know what a form is? A select box? Do you know how HTTP works? What a request parameter is? What a servlet is? What a JSP is? If you don't know anything of all this, you'll need several tutorials, and a whole lot of time to learn.